# Use Numpy to slices rows?

Tags: python, numpy, slice

Have table want to use numpy to slice into sections

```
table = ['212:3:0:70.13911:-89.85361:3', '212:3:1:70.28725:-89.77466:7', '212:3:2:70.39231:-89.74908:9',  '212:3:3:70.48806:-89.6414:11', '212:3:4:70.60366:-89.51539:14', '212:3:5:70.60366:-89.51539:14', '212:3:6:70.66518:-89.4048:16']

t = np.asarray (table, dtype ='object')
```

Want to use numpy to slice all........ `212:3:0, 212:3:1` as k. 
Want all `'212:3:0:70.13911:-89.85361:3','212:3:1:70.28725:-89.77466:7'` as v

into a dictionany dict (k,v). I dont want to use a for-loop to do this...
I have done this as for loop its slow.

NOTE: the row has ":",  but the ":" does mean the dict ':'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
dict( (t.rsplit(':', 3)[0], t) for t in table ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Basics of dict comprehensions

To convert something into a dict, you need to make it into an iterable that generates 2-sequences (anything that generates a sequence of two elements), like `[[1,2],[3,4]]` or `[(1,2),(3,4)]` or `zip([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8])`)

E.g.

```
>>> mylst = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
>>> print dict(mylst)
{1:2, 3:4, 5:6}
```

so you need to split each of your strings in such a way that you produce a
tuple.  say you've already written a function that does this, called
`split_item` that takes in a two strings and returns a tuple. You could then
write a generator expression like the following so that you don't need to load
everything into memory until you create the dict.

```
def generate_tuples(table):
    length = len(table)
    for i in range(1, length - 1):
        yield split_item(table[i-1], table[i])
```

then just call the `dict` builtin on your generator function.

```
>>> dict(generate_tuples(table))
```

Since you say you already wrote this with a for-loop, I'm guessing you already have a `split_items` function written.

#### Making it fast

Here's a guide to [high-performance Python](http://ianozsvald.com/HighPerformancePythonfromTrainingatEuroPython2011_v0.2.pdf), written by Ian Ozsvald, that can help you experiment with other ways to increase the speed of processing. (credit to @AndrewWalker 's [SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108869/optimizing-python-distance-calculation-while-accounting-for-periodic-boundary-co))

Comment: I want to use numpy in the solution. I dont want to use for loop. Numpy has methods for eval cols thats what Im after.

Comment: @Merlin - Numpy doesn't do string operations.  You're wanting string operations.  List comprehensions/loops/generations are what you're after.

Comment: @Merlin - The solution that was marked correct isn't using numpy.  And, no, numpy doesn't have fast text parsing. It doesn't parse text at all. If all of your strings are the same length, then, yes, you could use numpy to do it and it probably would be faster. At that point, you're treating strings as character arrays, though.