# Optimizing Python distance calculation while accounting for periodic boundary conditions

Tags: python, optimization, list-comprehension

I have written a Python script to calculate the distance between two points in 3D space while accounting for periodic boundary conditions. The problem is that I need to do this calculation for many, many points and the calculation is quite slow. Here is my function.

```
def PBCdist(coord1,coord2,UC):
    dx = coord1[0] - coord2[0]
    if (abs(dx) > UC[0]*0.5):
       dx = UC[0] - dx
    dy = coord1[1] - coord2[1]
    if (abs(dy) > UC[1]*0.5):
       dy = UC[1] - dy
    dz = coord1[2] - coord2[2]
    if (abs(dz) > UC[2]*0.5):
       dz = UC[2] - dz
    dist = np.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2)
    return dist
```

I then call the function as so

```
for i, coord2 in enumerate(coordlist):
  if (PBCdist(coord1,coord2,UC) < radius):
      do something with i
```

Recently I read that I can greatly increase performance by using list comprehension. The following works for the non-PBC case, but not for the PBC case

```
coord_indices = [i for i, y in enumerate([np.sqrt(np.sum((coord2-coord1)**2)) for coord2 in coordlist]) if y < radius]
for i in coord_indices:
   do something
```

Is there some way to do the equivalent of this for the PBC case? Is there an alternative that would work better?

Comment: You are using NumPy, so you should vectorise the loop to improve performance.  What exactly is the structure of `coordlist`?  It should be a two-dimensional NumPy array to be able to optimise the loop with NumPy ufuncs.

Comment: coordlist is a numpy array with shape approx (5711,3). coordlist itself comes from a larger list, so I effectively loop over coordlist 20,000 times and that list of coordlist gets looped over about 50 times...you get the picture.

Comment: I looked up the vectorize function in NumPy. The documentation says: ["The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

Comment: "Vectorising" in the context of NumPy means that you use NumPy ufuncs to move loops you would otherwise have to do in Python code to C code (like I did in my answer).  I recommend reading up on NumPy a bit if you are concerned about performance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should write your `distance()` function in a way that you can vectorise the loop over the 5711 points.  The following implementation accepts an array of points as either the `x0` or `x1` parameter:

```
def distance(x0, x1, dimensions):
    delta = numpy.abs(x0 - x1)
    delta = numpy.where(delta > 0.5 * dimensions, delta - dimensions, delta)
    return numpy.sqrt((delta ** 2).sum(axis=-1))
```

Example:

```
>>> dimensions = numpy.array([3.0, 4.0, 5.0])
>>> points = numpy.array([[2.7, 1.5, 4.3], [1.2, 0.3, 4.2]])
>>> distance(points, [1.5, 2.0, 2.5], dimensions)
array([ 2.22036033,  2.42280829])
```

The result is the array of distances between the points passed as second parameter to `distance()` and each point in `points`.

Comment: This led to about a 5 fold speed up in my code. Thanks! For those looking for an alternative, the answer by lazyr also performed just as well.

Comment: It makes no difference after taking the norm, but I like to get the right sign on delta by replacing the 3rd line by `delta = numpy.where(", delta - dimensions, ")`. Also note that `np.hypot` is better at avoiding overflow than sqrt(sum(x**2))

Comment: @Patrick `numpy.hypot()` only works for two dimensions, whereas the OP needed code that works for three-dimensional points.  And regarding the sign of `delta`, well, if you care, feel free to edit the post. :)

Comment: I think this might fail when points are not in adjacent boxes, but more than one box away from another.

Comment: @k1next Not sure what boxes you are talking about.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Okay I might have misread the question. If points were allowed to be outside of `dimensions` (and periodicity should still work), then your answer wouldn't work, but the one by Thaulow below would. But this wasn't asked here, so I'm sorry!

Answer (score 6):

```
import numpy as np

bounds = np.array([10, 10, 10])
a = np.array([[0, 3, 9], [1, 1, 1]])
b = np.array([[2, 9, 1], [5, 6, 7]])

min_dists = np.min(np.dstack(((a - b) % bounds, (b - a) % bounds)), axis = 2)
dists = np.sqrt(np.sum(min_dists ** 2, axis = 1))
```

Here `a` and `b` are lists of vectors you wish to calculate the distance between and `bounds` are the boundaries of the space (so here all three dimensions go from 0 to 10 and then wrap). It calculates the distances between `a[0]` and `b[0]`, `a[1]` and `b[1]`, and so on.

I'm sure numpy experts could do better, but this will probably be an order of magnitude faster than what you're doing, since most of the work is now done in C.

Comment: I tried this approach as well. It also led to about a 5 fold enhancement in code. Unfortunately I can only check 1 answer as the correct one :/

Comment: @johnjax For what it's worth, I would have accepted Sven Marnach's answer too, had I been in your shoes. It's more directly applicable than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that `meshgrid` is very useful for generating distances. For example:

```
import numpy as np
row_diff, col_diff = np.meshgrid(range(7), range(8))
radius_squared = (row_diff - x_coord)**2 + (col_diff - y_coord)**2
```

I now have an array (`radius_squared`) where every entry specifies the square of the distance from the array position `[x_coord, y_coord]`.

To circularize the array, I can do the following:

```
row_diff, col_diff = np.meshgrid(range(7), range(8))
row_diff = np.abs(row_diff - x_coord)
row_circ_idx = np.where(row_diff > row_diff.shape[1] / 2)
row_diff[row_circ_idx] = (row_diff[row_circ_idx] - 
                         2 * (row_circ_idx + x_coord) + 
                         row_diff.shape[1])
row_diff = np.abs(row_diff)
col_diff = np.abs(col_diff - y_coord)
col_circ_idx = np.where(col_diff > col_diff.shape[0] / 2)
col_diff[row_circ_idx] = (row_diff[col_circ_idx] - 
                         2 * (col_circ_idx + y_coord) + 
                         col_diff.shape[0])
col_diff = np.abs(row_diff)
circular_radius_squared = (row_diff - x_coord)**2 + (col_diff - y_coord)**2
```

I now have all the array distances circularized with vector math.